# TeamCity VCS Labeling build feature is not showing in the build log

Tags: svn, teamcity

I have added two VCS Labeling build features to my build but I can't see anything in the build log that refer to these features. below is how I configured the labeling pattern.

[image]

Comment: Do you see tha tags created in the svn repo ? I don;t think you seee any relevant information in the build logs

Comment: No I don't see any tags either :(